# Reverse pinvoke char *[] using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, managed, unmanagedexports

Im writing a plugin to a C++ project and I'm taking advantage of the UnmanagedExports Nuget package which allows the exposure of C functions in managed .NET Code. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

I have written a plugin which receives a string (defined as char * in c++)
Below is the UnmanagedExport method I have defined for this to work.

```
[DllExport("GetString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void GetString(StringBuilder MyString)
{            
    //Use and modify the StringBuilder. It receives the string passed and returns the modified version because it is being passed by reference. 
}
```

The above code runs beautifully.

Now the question is how can I pass a string array to my UnmanagedExport code. The C++ defines the call as requiring a char *[]

This does NOT work.

```
[DllExport("GetString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void GetString(StringBuilder[] MyString)
{            
}
```

Comment: Golden Rule is to first write a C function that takes the same arguments and, say, displays their value with printf().  You are completely guaranteed to discover the problem: *how long is the array?*  You don't know, C# doesn't know, Giesecke doesn't know.  Just don't skip that step when you don't understand unmanaged code well enough yet.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the input pointing me in the correct direction. Ive added my answer below, but this is only allowing me to pass in a string array. Changes to the array are not reflected in the caller code if it is modified.

Answer (score 0):

This allows the passing of a string[] but its just one way.

```
[DllExport("GetStrings", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void GetStrings([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]string[] MyStrings, int size)
{
    foreach(var s in MyStrings)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```